# Azure runbook powershell script to copy all webapp settings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to run the following script as a runbook to copy all settings from one webapp to another but I get the following error.

```
try
{   
    $acct = Get-AzureRmSubscription
}
catch
{
    Login-AzureRmAccount
}

$fromResourceGroup = 'resourceG1'
$fromSite = 'website1'
$toResourceGroup = 'resourceG2'
$toSite = 'website2'

$props = (Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $fromResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $fromSite/appsettings -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force).Properties

$hash = @{}
$props | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $hash[$_.Name] = $props.($_.Name) }

Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $toResourceGroup
        -Name $toSite -AppSettings $hash
```

exception:

```
Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:18 char:10
+ $props | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $hash[$_.Name] = $ ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Set-AzureRMWebApp : The term 'Set-AzureRMWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:20 char:1
+ Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $toResourceGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRMWebApp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-Name : The term '-Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:21 char:9
+         -Name $toSite -AppSettings $hash
+         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Name:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3):

An Automation Runbook use a different strategy for login, so you should not just copy a PowerShell script to a Runbook and expect it run exactly the same way as you run locally.

You see that the command `Login-AzureRmAccount` will popup a window asking for user name and password. But, in an Automation Runbook, it can't. Hence, you need to do something else in order to properly login.

1. Create a new Active Direcotry User for your automation.

   a. Log into the [Azure Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

   b. Select **Active Directory**, and click your default Active Directory.

   c. Click **User**, and click **Add User**. For **Type of User**, choose **New user in your organization**. It cannot be **User with an existing Microsoft account**, because it will fail when trying to login in a Runbook.

   d. On the **User Profile**, for **Roles**, a Service administrator is good enough, but if you want, you can choose Global administrator. Do not Enable Multi-Factor Authentication. If you do, again, it will fail when trying to login in a Runbook.

   e. Note the user’s full name and temporary password.

   f. Back to the Classic Portal, Click **Settings** > **Administrators** > **Add**. Type in the user name you got above, and select your subscription.

   g. Log out of Azure and then log back in with the account you just created. You will be prompted to change the user’s password.

   Note: If you already have a "non-Microsoft" and MFA-disabled user account, you can skip this step. For more information, see [Configuring Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-configuring/)
2. Create a PS credential asset for your Runbook.

   a. Log into the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), and choose your automation.

   b. In your automation account setting blade, click **Assets** > **Credential**.

   [image]

   c. Click **Add a credential**, enter Name, User name, and Password (the user name and password you create in the previous step), and click **Create**.

   [image]
3. Instead of simply using `Login-AzureRmAccount`, you should us the following to login.

   ```
   $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "<your credential name>"
   Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

`Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.`

means that $props is null, since you are passing it to Get-Member. So

`$props = (Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $fromResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $fromSite/appsettings -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force).Properties`

is evaluating to null for some reason.

This is probably because you are not authenticating to Azure correctly. Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-resource-manager-support-azure-automation-runbooks/ for more info.