# how to export and import Azure Function's "application settings"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to export and import Azure function's "application settings" ? I have added keys and need to move to new function app. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have few options here:

### Manually

You can do it manually by:

1. Go to https://resources.azure.com
2. Search for your app where your app settings are.
3. go to the "App Settings" view and copy all the JSON there in properties

[image]

4. go to your new app, and navigate to 'App settings' and click edit, and put all that in the properties collection.

### Automated:

You can use either the azure-cli, powershell, or azure-functions-core-tools to achieve the same thing.

#### Powershell:

Using the Azure Powershell modules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-5.4.0

```bsh
# get the app settings from app1
$resource = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <yourResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<yourFunctionAppName>/appsettings" -Action list -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force

# update the other app with $resource.Properties
New-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $resource.Properties -ResourceGroupName <targetResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<targetAppName>/appsettings" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force
```

#### azure-functions-core-tools:

The documentation for that tool is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

You can do the same by running

```sh
az login
func init myFunctionApp
cd myFunctionApp
# this will fetch your settings and put them in local.settings.json
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <yourAppName>
func azure functionapp publish <yourTargetApp> --publish-settings-only
```

the last switch `--publish-settings-only` is important to not overwrite the files if you only want to publish the settings.

#### azure-cli:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

This page should have some documentation about how to retrieve and set app settings using the cli https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-cli-app-service-storage?toc=%2fcli%2fazure%2ftoc.json

Comment: Thank you sir for saving my time :-)

Comment: for the first option let me add this sequence for easy navigation: subscriptions -> *your_subscription* -> resourceGroups -> *your_resourceGroup* -> providers -> Microsoft.Web -> sites -> *your_function* -> config -> appsettings

Comment: The settings downloaded via the resources.azure.com are not in the right format for `local.settings.json`.  The **azure functions-core-tools** heading will help if that's what you need.

Answer (score 5):

In your Function app checkout's main directory, run `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings`.  Use `func settings decrypt` if you need to edit it.

**This answer does not work any more - the Download App Content link is grey in the Azure portal**
You can also get them via the Azure portal:

1. Select your Functions App in the Azure portal.
2. Click **Download app content** in the top bar.
3. Select **Include app settings in the download**
4. Find the file `local.settings.json` in the download.

Comment: Ths is the correct answer, IMHO

Comment: This is short and perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is impossible. You could check this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/16830592-export-and-import-of-application-settings-from-web).

One solution, you could clone your web app, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning). When you clone a app, application settings are also cloned.

Another solution, you could use Power Shell to import application setting and copy the application to a new web app, using following example:

```
try{
    $acct = Get-AzureRmSubscription
}
catch{
    Login-AzureRmAccount
}

$myResourceGroup = '<your resource group>'
$mySite = '<your web app>'
$myResourceGroup2 = '<another resource group>'
$mySite2 = '<another web app>'

$props = (Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
        -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $mySite/appsettings `
        -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force).Properties

$hash = @{}
$props | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $hash[$_.Name] = $props.($_.Name) }

Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup2 `
        -Name $mySite2 -AppSettings $hash
```

More information about this please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118432/is-it-possible-to-easily-copy-applications-settings-from-one-web-app-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Postman.

You can get a JSON with all app settings by making a **GET** request to the following URL:

```
https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASS@$FUNCTION_APPNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings
```

Once the keys are returned you can make a **POST** request to the new function app's URL and copy that JSON result as the request body with a header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Username and password can be found from **Deployment Credentials** in the portal of your Function App.

Comment: This returns a load more settings than just the function app's application settings...

Answer (score 0):

I think [Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416450/5546686) is the easiest one, but just in case, I had the need of retrieving the local.settings.json formatted file from a specific slot (not the root app) that also has keyvault secrets.

So I created [this script](https://github.com/Makishi-UY/fetch-azure-function-local-settings) that gets the configs from an app or a slot app, formats them as a local.settings.json file and if there are keyvaults, it also resolves the values.

I hope it can help somebody, but actually, downloading the app content gives you the file.

Answer (score 0):

We can quickly view the json from the "function app → Configuration → Advanced Edit."

[image]